# Combine 3 MySQL queries to make 1 query

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I'm trying to build a search function into my site. If I want to search if a photo's title, text or tag contains the word 'black' I have these 3 queries:

```
SELECT id 
FROM photos 
WHERE title LIKE '%black%' 
AND status = 'A'

SELECT id 
FROM photos 
WHERE text LIKE '%black%' 
AND status = 'A'

SELECT DISTINCT(photos.id) 
FROM photos, photo_tags, tags 
WHERE tags.tag LIKE '%black%' 
AND photo_tags.keyid = tags.id 
AND photos.id = photo_tags.catid 
AND photos.status = 'A'
```

Is it possible to combine all of this into 1 query? I know I can join the first 2 however combining it with the third seems too complex for me. I've tried joining with OR but I don't think I'm doing it right.

Additionally I would like it so that there are no duplicate results, so if a photo has the title 'black' and the tag 'black' it would only show up once.

BTW the tables look something like this, the keyid relates to the tag.id and the catid relates to the photos.id

```
photos

+----+-----------+-----------------+
| id | title     | text            |
+----+-----------------------------+
|  1 | blue pic  | black and blue  |
|  2 | red pic   | red and green   |
|  3 | green pic | green and white |
|  4 | white pic | white and black |
|  5 | black pic | black and gold  |
+----+-----------+-----------------+

tags

+----+-------+
| id | tag   |
+----+-------+
|  1 | blue  |
|  2 | table |
|  3 | chair |
|  4 | red   |
|  5 | black |
+----+-------+

photo_tags

+-------+-------+
| keyid | catid |
+-------+-------+
|  1    | 1     |
|  2    | 1     |
|  3    | 2     |
|  4    | 2     |
|  5    | 5     |
+-------+-------+
```

Comment: the 1st query is searching the title column, the 2nd query is searching the text column. i know that isn't too difficult to combine both into 1 query but it's the addition of the 3rd query which is  confusing me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you should join the tables and then filter by the text you're looking for in both tables:

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.id FROM photos p
JOIN photo_tags pt ON pt.cat_id = p.id
JOIN tags t ON pt.key_id = t.id
WHERE (p.title LIKE '%black%' OR t.tag LIKE '%black%') AND p.status = 'A'
```

Comment: That's it - I knew there was a simple query out there! I added "OR p.text LIKE '%black%'" to WHERE and it works like a charm - thanks so much

Answer (score 0):

```
First statement could be your answer. Not sure if you are looking for below output:-

ysql> SELECT DISTINCT(photos.id) FROM photos, photo_tags, tags WHERE tags.tag L
IKE '%black%'AND photos.title LIKE '%black%' AND photo_tags.keyid = tags.id AND
photos.id = photo_tags.catid;
+------+
| id   |
+------+
|    5 |
+------+
1 row in set (0.05 sec)


mysql> SELECT id
    -> FROM photos
    -> WHERE title LIKE '%black%' ;
+------+
| id   |
+------+
|    5 |
+------+
1 row in set (0.08 sec)

mysql> SELECT id
    -> FROM photos
    -> WHERE text LIKE '%black%';
+------+
| id   |
+------+
|    1 |
|    4 |
|    5 |
+------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT DISTINCT(photos.id)
    -> FROM photos, photo_tags, tags
    -> WHERE tags.tag LIKE '%black%'
    -> AND photo_tags.keyid = tags.id
    -> AND photos.id = photo_tags.catid ;
+------+
| id   |
+------+
|    5 |
+------+
1 row in set (0.05 sec)



mysql> SELECT DISTINCT(photos.id) FROM photos, photo_tags, tags WHERE tags.tag L
IKE '%black%'AND photos.title LIKE '%black%' AND photo_tags.keyid = tags.id AND
photos.id = photo_tags.catid;
+------+
| id   |
+------+
|    5 |
+------+
1 row in set (0.05 sec)
```